# Python regex. I'm trying to drop text at the first occurrence of any word after a certain word(Total_Cases)

Tags: python, regex

so in this case drop everything from word Star ( can be any word!) after word (Total_Cases)

```
test1 = '/nOpenCases -  4  -   -   -  4  /nClosed_Cases 6  -  -  -  - 6  /nTotal_Cases 3  4 -  -  - 7  Rocket Star Services Limited Term Disability FLK1234567 As Of 12/21/2023 property of xyz. Use and distribution limited solely to personnel. © Copyright 2020 Rocket Corporation) 9 of 15  Created: 3:20 PM - 1/21/2020'
```

I want:

```
'/nOpenCases -  4  -   -   -  4  /nClosed_Cases 6  -  -  -  - 6  /nTotal_Cases 3 4 -  -  - 7
```

I've tried this -

```
re.sub('(?<=Total_Claims)(.*)',"", test1)
```

but this one results in -

```
'/nOpenCases -  1  -   -   -  1  /nClosed_Cases 3  -  -  -  - 3  /nTotal_Cases
```

this one drops the numbers too...

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(Total_Cases.*?)\S+\s+Star.*', r'\1', test1)`. Or, also try `(Total_Cases.*?)\D+Star.*` regex

Comment: The word (star) will be different everytime so like it will be a word but not the same word! Like i'm trying something like [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Then, `(Total_Cases[\s\d-]*\d).*`? Or `(Total_Cases[^a-zA-Z]*).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
result = re.sub(r'(Total_Cases[^a-zA-Z]*).*', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hw70cC/1)

**Details**

- `(Total_Cases[^a-zA-Z]*)` - Capturing group #1: `Total_Cases` and then any 0 or more characters other than ASCII letters
- `.*`  - any 0 or more chars to the end of the string (`flags=re.S` enables `.` to match across line breaks).

The `\1` in the replacement pattern refers to Group 1 value. `.rstrip()` will remove any trailing whitespace (remove if unnecessary).